# How to create and push data into Nested JSON object in Spring boot Entity class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

My data looks something like this -

How I can create an Entity with Setter, Getter and how to push the data into specific API (Like firstAPI, secondAPI and thirdAPI)?

```
{
   "firstApi": [
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Ron"
    ],
   "secondApi": [
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Gita"
    ],
    "thirdApi": [
       "id": 3,
       "name": "Mita"
    ]
}
```

It is very easy in Javascript, I am new to spring boot, any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson:

```
 class API{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  API() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

// Serialization
API obj = new API();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);

API obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, API.class);
```

and update the string and serialize.

Also you can access as a JSON object too and this is not Gson

```
    J

SONObject obj= new JSONObject();
        JSONArray Arr = new JSONArray();

//      Add the values in newly created empty array 

        Arr.add("Add your inner object");
        obj.put("firstApi", Arr);
```